# Android app not rendering html tags very well

Tags: java, android, html, android-studio

This is what i am getting from web service in string.

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;This is instructor&amp;#39;s reply to the guest&amp;#39;s MDB message&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

This is how i am setting it to text view

```
String Reply = parent.getString(TAG_ReplyMessage);
TextView ReplyTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reply_txt);
ReplyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(Reply));
```

but app shows information with `<p>` and `<strong>` tags.

[image]

Whereas it should render those tags, not to display it's html.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It may help you**
I was also getting same issue in my project and this worked for me.may be it will help you:

```
String reply = parent.getString(TAG_ReplyMessage);
TextView ReplyTextView = findViewById(R.id.reply_txt);
String htmltext = Html.fromHtml(reply).toString();
ReplyTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmltext));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write those tags directly between `<![CDATA[...]]>` in `strings.xml`.

Example:

```
<string name="type"><![CDATA[Type:<B> %s</B>]]></string>
```

In Java:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.type, "Sports")));
```

Output:

Type: **Sports**

**Update:**

If string itself is like:

```
String data = "&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;This is instructor&amp;#39;s reply to the guest&amp;#39;s MDB message&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/p&gt;";
```

Then, you can try as below:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(Html.fromHtml(data).toString()));
```

Comment: Well i am getting that string from web service. why i need to add it to strings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support all HTML tags.

This is a, albeit a bit old, list of supported HTML tags:
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-quick-tip-formatting-text-with-html-fromhtml/

Or you could look through the sources and see which are supported:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/text/Html.java#Html

According to those lists, `<p>` is not supported. So it can't parse anything within `<p></p>`.

Answer (score 0):

`&amp;#39;` remove `amp;` part. Html code for `'` single quote is just `&#39;`