# HTML string is not rendering in textview

Tags: android, html, textview

i have a json data like this

```
{
"user_id": "27",
"notification": "<a>There is package wiating for you to pick from <font style="color: blue;"> #Surat</font> to <font style = "color: blue;"> #Adajan, Surat, Gujarat, India</font> </a>",
},
{
"user_id": "27",
"notification": "<a>There is package wiating for you to pick from <font style="color: blue;"> #majuraget, surat</font> to <font style = "color: blue;"> #pal, surat</font> </a>",
},
{
"user_id": "27",
"notification": "<a>There is package wiating for you to pick from <font style="color: blue;"> #majuraget, surat</font> to <font style = "color: blue;"> #pal, surat</font> </a>",
},
{
"user_id": "27",
"notification": "<a>There is package wiating for you to pick from <font style="color: blue;"> #majuraget, surat</font> to <font style = "color: blue;"> #pal, surat</font> </a>",
}
```

i m rendering this notification string in Textview but its not working.

this is what i tried

```
Spanned value = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

            value = Html.fromHtml(notifications.getTitle(), Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT);
            holder.txtTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            holder.txtTitle.setText(value);

        }else {
            value = Html.fromHtml(notifications.getTitle());
            holder.txtTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            holder.txtTitle.setText(value);     
        }
```

i also tried this [library](https://github.com/Pixplicity/HtmlCompat):

```
Spanned fromHtml = HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context, notifications.getTitle(), 0);
        holder.txtTitle.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(fromHtml);
```

but none of this is work.

this is what i get as output:

[image]

and this is what i expect

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42389878/android-app-not-rendering-html-tags-very-well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifing the notification string like this:

```
{
"user_id": "27",
"notification": "<a>There is package wiating for you to pick from <font color='blue'> #majuraget, surat</font> to <font color='blue'> #pal, surat</font> </a>"
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. its worked..  so the styles is not rendering on android side.. only attribute does.